# Confluence keyboard shortcut markup

Tags: markup, confluence

On [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/), I can use markup for keyboard shortcuts like `<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>` for <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>.

Is something like this also possible in [Confluence](https://de.atlassian.com/software/confluence)? If yes, how?

Comment: I can't prove this, because of the lack of any evidence, but I am almost 100% certain there is no functionality like this in confluence. The best you could do would be to insert little images of the keyboard shortcuts.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried it yet, but it seems the free official [plugin](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/com.atlassian.plugins.confluence.markdown.confluence-markdown-macro) **Markdown Macro for Confluence** will help you to use any Markdown syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Two solutions found on Atlassian's forums:

The [first](https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Confluence-questions/How-can-I-insert-text-into-the-document-and-preserve-destination/qaq-p/233514) is to

> Paste table row `<kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>` in the Confluence's shortcuts

The [second](https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Confluence-questions/How-do-you-show-the-Keyboard-symbols-on-my-own-confluence-pages/qaq-p/168981) is to add your own CSS to the page, which is not ideal:

> This is done with a combination of CSS and HTML.
>
> Start with a CSS macro (or edit the Look and Feel):
>
> ```
> kbd &gt; kbd {
>   box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.2);
>   border-radius: 3px;
>   padding: .1em .7em;
>   border: 1px solid #ccc;
>   font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
>   background-color: ;
>   display: inline-block;
>   margin: 0 .1em;
>   white-space: nowrap;
>   font-size: 1em;
> }
> ```
>
> Then wrap the key letters and words in HTML:
>
> `&lt;kbd&gt;&lt;kbd&gt;K&lt;/kbd&gt;&lt;/kbd&gt;`